# Initialization error while trying to connect to Oracle using SQLDeveloper

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, oracle-11g, plsql, sqldeveloper

I've installed Oracle 11.2.0 and Allround Automations' SQLDeveloper on Windows 7 64-bit.

When I run SQLDeveloper and and try to connect to Oracle, I get the below error:

```
Initialization error
Could not load "C:\app\MyComp\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll"

OCIDLL forced to C:\app\MyComp\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll
LoadLibrary(C:\app\MyComp\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll) returned 0
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because PL/SQL Developer is incapable of loading 64-bit version of oci.dll file. To fix this, download the 32-bit version of [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html), extract it to a directory such as \instant_client.

Next, configure PL/SQL Developer to use this version by clicking on Tool menus -> Preferences. Under Oracle Home, point to the location where you had extracted Instant client (\instant_client, in this case)  and under location of OCI Library, point to the oci.dll file present in location where you had extracted Instant client ( \instant_client\oci.dll). Restart PL/SQL Developer and you should be able to connect now.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might see this thread in the future -

1. You must put the full file name of the "32 bit" oci.dll (path + \ + oci.dll)
2. You should check "Force OCI7 mode on OCI8"
3. One last step I forgot to add yesterday: You must add a system variable (my computer->right click->properties->Advanced system settings->Environment variables) Name of variable = TNS_ADMIN, value = oracle folder....client_1\network\admin (that is where your "tnsnames.ora" file is)

Look here:
http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=37996

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and Ihad to specify the complete file path of oci.dll alongwith the actual oci.dll filename.

Comment: could you write instructions - how and where did you do it. I have /instantclient folder in the PATH variable.. the oci.dll is in it